# Change training parameters in the config file after training for a certain number of steps using the Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have trained an Inception Resnet v2 model on a dataset for 61000 steps so far with the following values in the configuration file of the model:

```py
adam_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 150000
            learning_rate: .0001
          }
```

Now, If I want to reduce the learning rate of my model from now on, will making the below change:

```py
adam_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 60000
            learning_rate: .0001
          }
```

And restarting from the checkpoint actually reduces the learning rate of my model from `0.0003` to `0.0001` since the number of steps that it has already trained for so far is greater than 60000?
If not, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use the already trained 61000 steps model file as the fine-tune checkpoint and then you can modify the lr as you like. In this case, you are essentially training from step 1.

Comment: So you mean to say that if I use the trained 61000 steps model file as the fine-tune checkpoint, I should change the line `initial_learning_rate: ` to `0.0001` instead of `0.0003` since training begins from step 1 ?

Comment: But just for the sake of clarification, I have noticed that if I have a checkpoint saved at 61000, after I resume again,the next step begins at 61001 and not 1. So does this step 1 use the `initial_learning_rate` or the learning rate set after step 60000 in the config file(if I have set a learning rate decay after step 60000 in the middle of training)?

Comment: Here is what I suggest, make a backup of all files inside of the `model` folder, remove them and retry it. Because TensorFlow object detection would automatically resume from the last saved checkpoint if there is such a file inside of the saved model folder. As for the learning rate, if you start at step 1, it should be `initial_learning_rate`

Comment: Ok, I will try that. My doubt is, in case I resume from the previous checkpoint(step 61001), it would be interpreted as 61001 and not step 1 right? If that is the case, then I suppose the learning rate should be 0.0001. Please let me know if I have understood this correctly

Comment: Yes, you are right. Directly resuming would start with step 61001, giving you the learning rate of 1e-4

Answer (score -2):

goto to your config file and search this node then add the bold line train_config: { **num_steps: 5000**

Comment: Hi NobDev, how does this answer the question?